# how to reference an object stored within an object

Tags: javascript, object

I tracking aircraft, and need to check on their positions. In this case, I have stored the last reported position in an object created to contain pertinent info on that aircraft, current position being one of them:

```
       aircraft.currentPosition = L.latLng([posUpdate.record[i].lat, posUpdate.record[i].lon]);
```

Now elsewhere in the code I am trying to use that lat/lon to set a marker, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pull out the data. I have tried:

```
    lat = aircraft.currentPositon.lat;
    lat = aircraft.currentPositon.['lat'];
    lat = aircraft.currentPositon.[0];
    lat = aircraft.currentPositon.L.lat;
    lat = aircraft.currentPositon.LatLng.lat;
```

But everything returns a variation of

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'L' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'L' of undefined
```

'L' being replaced by whatever variant I'm trying. I know the data is there, here is what shown in the console output:

```
currentPosition:  M {lat: 37.71325349807739, lng: -122.1666169166565}
                  lat: 37.71325349807739
                  lng: -122.1666169166565
                  _proto_: Object
```

Is there a some way to get to the object data?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
lat = aircraft.currentPosition['lat'];
```

You might have misspell *currentPosition*

Comment: Duh. It was the misspelling that was doing it. I've been dorking with this for 45 minutes now and never saw the spelling mistake. Thanks!